# Advice on how to design a datastructure

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a file from which I am reading the data.
I need advice on how to design the data structure which does the following:
So, the data is of form

```
id_1::id_2::similiarity_score
```

Now, though the data is in this form but it also means that

```
id_2::id_1::same_similiarity_Score
```

So, what I want is a datastructure which when I use in program.
So lets say I want to use this data in order to find which two items are similar

```
object.maxSimiliarity(object_id_1)
returns object_id_2 # has max score
```

but then this object_id_1 can also be in product_id_2 column in the database...

so in database in can be either of form:

```
 object_id_1:: object_id_2::score
 or object_id2::object_id_1::score
```

so I sort off want to design this datastructure in a way that

```
k_1, k_2:: value <--> k_2,k_1::value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you could use the scores to build lists of best to worst matches:

```
d = {
     'id1':  [id_best_match_to_id1, id_next_best_match_to_id1, ..., id_worst_match_to_id1],
     'id2':  [id_best_match_to_id2, id_next_best_match_to_id2, ..., id_worst_match_to_id2],
     ...
}
```

If the similarity scores need to be retained, use a list of tuples in the form `(id_best_match_to_id1, similarity_score_to_id1)`.

I don't see a way to exploit that similarity is a symmetric relation where `sim(x,y)==sim(y,x)`.

Comment: Hmm.. I guess you are right.. unless I waste the space and save both (x,y) and (y,x) Thanks for the quick turn around

Comment: Glad to help.  FWIW, there isn't much space wasted.  Python's lists just use pointers to the underlying objects so (x,y)==(y,x) costs you almost nothing :-)

Answer (score 3):

A general trick for this sort of thing is to find a canonicalisation - a function that maps all members of a particular class to the same object. In this case, you might achieve it by sorting the first two components, which will transform B::A::Score to A::B::Score, while leaving A::B::Score as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The data look very much like nodes and edges of a weighted graph. If `a` is similar to `b` with a score `5.0`, and similar to `c` with a score `1.0`, you might visualise it thus:

```
                                    a
                                   / \
                                  /   \
                                5.0   1.0
                                /       \
                               b         c
```

[Networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) is a python lib that provides ready-made graph objects and algorithms. Loading up your data into a weighted multigraph (that is, it supports multiple connections between nodes `A--B` and `B--A` is trivial. After that, getting the most similar object given an object id is a case of finding the node, finding it's most weighted edge and returning the node at the end of it.

```
import networkx as nx

## Test data
data = """\
a::b::2
b::a::3
a::c::5
b::e::1
"""
rows = (row.split('::') for row in data.split())


class Similarity(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.g = nx.MultiGraph()
        self.load(data)

    def load(self, data):
        ## Turn the row into data suitable for networkx graph
        rows = ((row[0], row[1], float(row[2])) for row in data)
        self.g.add_weighted_edges_from(rows)

    def most_similar(self, obj_id):
        ## Get edges from obj_id node
        edges = self.g.edges_iter(obj_id, data=True)
        ## Sort by weight, get first, get joined node
        return sorted([(i[0], i[1], i[2].get('weight', 0)) for i in edges])[-1][1]


sc = Similarity(rows)
sc.most_similar('a') ## 'c'
## Add some more data linking a --> f with a high score
sc.load([('a', 'f', 10)])
sc.most_similar('a') ## 'f'
```